# Asp.Net Gridview imagefield populated from database (img src empty)

Tags: c#, asp.net

http://postimg.org/gallery/2lkmvvoyc/
Code,
Database,
Gridview,
GridviewBind,
InspectElement(img src empty),
MethodReturn

Comment: instead of set DataImageUrlField from database, try hard code path, and see, image displayed or not?

Comment: instead of setting the absolute path, use relative path of Image URl. That's It. Where you exteute your SP, and setting the object a.ImagePath Attributes, use relative path

Comment: If you view source of your page (i.e. show HTML), then do you see the `src` attribute of the `img` populated?

Comment: nope img src is is empty, if i try hard core i get this error                            A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:), whats the syntax for getting relative path?